# Unable to install Git plugin for Eclipse (RAD 9.0.1.2)

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, installation, ibm-rad

I was previously able to install a Git plugin I have into RAD 9. But after reinstalling RAD, I'm unable to install the plugin again. I keep getting this error:

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=IBM Software Delivery Platform 
    com.ibm.sdp.eclipse.ide, 
    phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, 
    operand=null --> 
        [R]org.eclipse.egit.core.source 3.5.0.201409260305-r,action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.AddSourceBundleAction).
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.utils.SimpleConfiguratorUtils
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.utils.SimpleConfiguratorUtils
```

I'm not really sure what this error means. Has anyone else experienced this or know what to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi did you solved this for yourself..? if yes.. could you please tell me how..

Comment: @user1912935 it works now, but I honestly don't know why. I tried numerous times and it finally started working after about 6-7 weeks. I don't remember if there's anything specific I did during that time, sorry.

Comment: Btw, I do have another Eclipse installed (not RAD) with the plugin, idk if that plugin installation was some how interfering with RAD's whole time.